# I want to find out all the palindrome prime numbers between 2 numbers. My code can find the palindrome numbers but also prints the non primes

Tags: python, palindrome

Non-prime numbers are being printed because it checks only from '2-10' for prime numbers. How can I change the code to check for all numbers upto x?

```
N = eval(input("Enter the starting point N: \n"))
M = eval(input("Enter the ending point M: \n"))

n = str(N)

i = 0


for j in range(N, M):
    if (n[i] == n[len(n)-1]):
        x = N
        N = N + 1
        if not((x % 2 == 0) or (x % 3 == 0) or (x % 4 == 0) or (x % 5 == 0) or (x % 6 == 0) or (x % 7 == 0) or (x % 8 == 0) or (x % 9 == 0) or (x % 10 == 0)):
            print(x)
        n = str(N)

    else:
        N = N + 1
        n = str(N)
```

Comment: The easiest way is to have a range. For numbers in that range convert to strings. If the string is an even length, split it and check to see if they are the same (you can sort both sides to make it even easier) if the string length is odd, split the string in half ommiting the center number.

Comment: Also, you should break your code down. One function to check and print non primes and one to find palindromes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) that I wrote. It pretty efficiently finds all the prime numbers less than the number you pass it. I would explain it to you, but Wikipedia (linked above) does a much better job than I could. Use it to generate the prime numbers and then iterate through the list it returns to check if those numbers are palindromes.

```
def primeslt(n):
    """Finds all primes less than n"""

    if n < 3:
        return []

    A = [True] * n
    A[0], A[1] = False, False

    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if A[i]:
            j = i**2
            while j < n:
                A[j] = False
                j += i

    return [num for num in range(n) if A[num]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a palindrome snippet

```
low_range = input()
high_range = input()
string_convertor = str

for num in range(int(low_range), int(high_range)):
    num_to_string = string_convertor(num)
    reverse = num_to_string[::-1]
    if num_to_string == reverse:
        print("Palindrome")
        print(num_to_string)
```

Comment: It's very inefficient to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Then create a local that does the job of str() see https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips, in python you have many ways to implement the same things (like most programming languages) This is efficient in terms of how long it took to type.  If more speed is needed then you go back and refactor and also as an example of how to check for palindromes.